# Entity Framework Generates Wrong SQL with LEFT OUTER JOINS

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework

We have .NET 4.5 installed, so we shouldn't be affected by known bugs like this one from previous versions of EF. Entity Framework is generating bad SQL. I have the following query

```
from a in _practiceRepository.Adjustments       
                                  select new AdjustmentAndFinancialInformation
                                             {
                                                 IsReport = true,
                                                 BillingProvider = a.InvoiceReceivable.Invoice.BillingProvider.User.UserName,
                                                 ServiceLocation = a.InvoiceReceivable.Invoice.Encounter.ServiceLocation.Name,
                                                 BillingOrganization = a.InvoiceReceivable.Invoice.BillingProvider.BillingOrganization.Name,
                                                 FinancialTypeGroup = "",
                                                 AdjustmentTypeName = a.AdjustmentType.Name,
                                                 AdjustmentTypeShortName = a.AdjustmentType.ShortName,
                                                 IsDebit = a.AdjustmentType.IsDebit,
                                                 IsCash = a.AdjustmentType.IsCash,
                                                 FinancialInformationTypeName = "",
                                                 FinancialInformationTypeShortName = "",
                                                 DateTimePosted = a.PostedDateTime,
                                                 PatientLastName = a.InvoiceReceivable.Invoice.Encounter.Patient.LastName,
                                                 PatientFirstName = a.InvoiceReceivable.Invoice.Encounter.Patient.FirstName,
                                                 PatientId = a.InvoiceReceivable.Invoice.Encounter.Patient.Id,
                                                 Amount = a.Amount,
                                                 InvoiceDateTime = a.InvoiceReceivable.Invoice.DateTime
                                             };
```

it generates the following SQL with a ton of LEFT JOINS (which degrades performance approximately 10x).

I've verified multiple times that all relationships are non-nullable.

```
    SELECT TOP (10) 
[Project1].[AdjustmentTypeId] AS [AdjustmentTypeId], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
[Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project1].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
[Project1].[Name3] AS [Name2], 
[Project1].[Name2] AS [Name3], 
[Project1].[ShortName] AS [ShortName], 
[Project1].[IsDebit] AS [IsDebit], 
[Project1].[IsCash] AS [IsCash], 
[Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project1].[C3] AS [C3], 
[Project1].[PostedDateTime] AS [PostedDateTime], 
[Project1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Project1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Project1].[PatientId] AS [PatientId], 
[Project1].[Amount] AS [Amount], 
[Project1].[DateTime] AS [DateTime]
FROM (SELECT
    [Extent1].[Amount] AS [Amount], 
    [Extent1].[PostedDateTime] AS [PostedDateTime], 
    [Extent1].[AdjustmentTypeId] AS [AdjustmentTypeId], 
    [Extent5].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
    [Extent8].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent11].[Name] AS [Name1], 
    [Extent12].[Name] AS [Name2], 
    [Extent12].[ShortName] AS [ShortName], 
    [Extent12].[IsCash] AS [IsCash], 
    [Extent12].[IsDebit] AS [IsDebit], 
    [Extent13].[Name] AS [Name3], 
    [Extent16].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
    [Extent19].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Extent21].[PatientId] AS [PatientId], 
    [Extent22].[DateTime] AS [DateTime], 
    cast(1 as bit) AS [C1], 
    N'' AS [C2], 
    N'' AS [C3]
    FROM                      [model].[Adjustments] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[InvoiceReceivables] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[InvoiceReceivableId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[Invoices] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[InvoiceId] = [Extent3].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[Providers] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[BillingProviderId] = [Extent4].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[Users] AS [Extent5] ON ([Extent4].[UserId] = [Extent5].[Id]) AND ([Extent5].[__EntityType__] IN (N'User',N'Doctor'))
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[Invoices] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent2].[InvoiceId] = [Extent6].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[Encounters] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[EncounterId] = [Extent7].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[ServiceLocations] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent7].[ServiceLocationId] = [Extent8].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[Invoices] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent2].[InvoiceId] = [Extent9].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[Providers] AS [Extent10] ON [Extent9].[BillingProviderId] = [Extent10].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[BillingOrganizations] AS [Extent11] ON ([Extent10].[BillingOrganizationId] = [Extent11].[Id]) AND ([Extent11].[__EntityType__] IN (N'BillingOrganization',N'PersonBillingOrganization'))
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[AdjustmentTypes] AS [Extent12] ON [Extent1].[AdjustmentTypeId] = [Extent12].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[FinancialTypeGroups] AS [Extent13] ON [Extent12].[FinancialTypeGroupId] = [Extent13].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[Invoices] AS [Extent14] ON [Extent2].[InvoiceId] = [Extent14].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[Encounters] AS [Extent15] ON [Extent14].[EncounterId] = [Extent15].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[Patients] AS [Extent16] ON [Extent15].[PatientId] = [Extent16].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[Invoices] AS [Extent17] ON [Extent2].[InvoiceId] = [Extent17].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[Encounters] AS [Extent18] ON [Extent17].[EncounterId] = [Extent18].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[Patients] AS [Extent19] ON [Extent18].[PatientId] = [Extent19].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[Invoices] AS [Extent20] ON [Extent2].[InvoiceId] = [Extent20].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[Encounters] AS [Extent21] ON [Extent20].[EncounterId] = [Extent21].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [model].[Invoices] AS [Extent22] ON [Extent2].[InvoiceId] = [Extent22].[Id]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[DateTime] ASC
```

How can I get Entity Framework to work correctly and generate the correct SQL?

Comment: I would suggest writing a stored proc if what it generates is needs performance tuning. EntityFramwework can execute stored procs.

Comment: the problem seems to be that it's generating a Left Outer Join for each table as you are moving away from the original table.  i.e. `a.InvoiceReceivable.Invoice.BillingProvider.BillingOrganization.Name` is joining 5 tables in order to find the value at the end.

Comment: Yes, and that is totally incorrect.

Comment: Can you file this on http://entityframework.codeplex.com? We made some improvements with LEFT OUTER JOINS in EF6 (https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/486, https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/199) but there still might be things we could improve. Please provide a repro with the model. Thanks!

Comment: Will do Pawel. Is there anything you can suggest to improve the present situation?

Comment: I just had the same problem upgrading from EF5 to EF6. I had correct sql with EF5, but everything turned to left outer in EF6 and now some queries timeout where they ran in 0 seconds before. Seems really weird. I supposed EF team did some regression tests...

Answer (score 0):

I did a test with the following code:

```
 using (TestEntities context = new TestEntities())
        {
            var qry = from a in context.Adjustments
                      join b in context.InvoiceReceivables on a.ID equals b.AdjustmentID
                      join c in context.Invoices on b.ID equals c.InvoiceRecievableID
                      select new { a.Name, IRName = b.Name, IName = c.Name};


            var list = qry.ToList();
        }
```

It generated the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1], 
[Extent3].[Name] AS [Name2]
FROM   [dbo].[Adjustments] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[InvoiceReceivable] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[AdjustmentID]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Invoice] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[ID] = [Extent3].[InvoiceRecievableID]
```

It looks like your model has 5 tables that have a 1:1 relationship and you have used a table per class approach. You could consider a table per heirarchy.

Comment: Changing strategy on databases that are not managed by EF is not an option. EF is supposed to join correctly regardless of using TPT, TPC or TPH.

Comment: I am not saying that you have to change the strategy. The Linq example I gave works without changing the strategy. However, from what I can see you would get better performance with TPH

Comment: I am already using TPH, so the bug in EF is unrelated to that.